# Percent of Value graph in DevExpress Grid Cell

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, devexpress

I need to represent a percent of value as a graph in DevExpress grid cell. I am able to paint using DrawLine but my problem is as soon as the percent value is equal to greater than 1 it is treated as 100%  in this code. Please find the code below, As shown in the screenshot, 3.59 should be shown less than 8.35! Please help.

```
private void CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs args)
{
    args.Appearance.DrawBackground(args.Graphics, args.Cache, args.Bounds);
      if (column != null)
      {
        int penSize = args.Bounds.Height * 2 / 3;
        double value = GetValue(); // This is the value against which I have to display the graph, its in %.

        int left = args.Bounds.Left;
        int middle = args.Bounds.Height / 2 + args.Bounds.Top;
        int width = args.Bounds.Width;

        int right = (int)(left + width * value);
        args.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Green, penSize), left, middle, right, middle);

       }        
    args.Handled = true;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Seem like `right` should be: `int right = (int)(width * (value/100)). The width of the line drawn should be relative the width of the cell's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int right = (int)(left + width * value);
```

This code calculates the bar length correctly only if the **value** is between 0 and 1. If values are between 0 and 100 or between 0 and 10, you need to divide the result of multiplying by 100 or 10 correspondingly.

```
int right = (int)(left + width * value / 100);
```

By the way, it is not necessary to puzzle over custom drawing, because you are using XtraGrid. There is the [RepositoryItemProgressBar](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemProgressBartopic) component, which can be embedded into XtraGrid cell. It displays the line according to the cell value and allows you to define the maximum and minimum value, so that the line is most exactly visualize the cell value. Read this article to learn how to assign editors to columns: [Assigning Editors to Columns and Card Fields](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument746)